# No Javascript support in Visual Studio 2017 for some project types

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

When I create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application in VS 2017, I get great Javascript support, e.g. Intellisense and formatting. On the top of the file are three dropdowns indicating the scope of where the cursor is in the project.

When I open a Javascript file in one of my older projects, e.g. when I open a local website directly, I get none of this Javascript support. The three dropdowns are empty and the only thing I really get is code coloring. I am opening the file using the same VS default Javascript editor.

Any reasons why the Javascript support would only work in some project types?

Comment: It might depend on your JS versions, but check [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/218740/vs2017-debug-javascript-files-not-working-1.html) link

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not about the project type, but instead that I used

```
/// <reference path = "path-to-scriptfile" />
```

statements in some javascript files. I think, VS 2017 does not support those statements anymore and using them ruined my JS support, which somehow even infected other files in the project that did not have such references.